# Running files using the * command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Let's say I wish to run all the scripts in a directory. If I do ./*.sh, which order will they run in?

Directory:
1.sh
2.sh
3.sh

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: Seems like a 'superuser' question.....

Comment: @JimGarrison Just trying it, will not suffice here. Observed output might be influenced by some unknown settings. This is definitely not a `-2` question. Just trying something, and reasoning that this will work on all other machines, is really BAD practice. Poor comment for 35k.. But what means 35k..... :)

Comment: Note that this will *not* run all the scripts. It will run the first script with the names of the remaining scripts passed as arguments to the first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run all the scripts, you must run them separately:

```
for f in ./*; do
    "$f"
done
```

The pattern will produce an alphabetically sorted list of scripts, where "alphabetical" is defined by your current locale.

Your attempt:

```
 ./*
```

would expand to a list of matching files, which the shell would then treat as a single command. The first script would be executed, with the remaining script names passed as arguments to the first.

Comment: Good Answer! Wouldn't have expected that.

Answer (score 6):

They are alphabetically sorted. From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion):

> After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set (see The Set Builtin), Bash scans each word for the characters ‘*’, ‘?’, and ‘[’. If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of file names matching the pattern.

However, in order to run them as you expect, you'll **need to read @chepners** answer (Thanks!, I must admit that I wouldn't expected that)

Comment: Now that you know the default order, you can try some tricks with ls sorting if you want to force the scripts to run in another order. For example, sorting them backwards alphabetically: "ls *.sh -r | xargs -I % bash%" or by creation time: "ls *.sh -t | xargs -I % bash %"